# Pandas selecting dates with more than 1 day gap in time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as:

```
df.ix[1:5]
  Date         A  
1 2010-07-26   3.15  
2 2010-07-27   5  
3 2010-07-30   3  
4 2010-07-31   105  
5 2010-08-01   0.05  
6 2010-08-02   0.05  
7 2010-08-05   0.05
```

I want to select only the columns where the consecutive dates have difference of more than 2 days. i.e. final result should be

```
  Date         A  
1 2010-07-27   5  
2 2010-07-30   3  
3 2010-08-02   0.05  
4 2010-08-05   0.05
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Edit:
The result row starts at `2010-07-27` as `2010-07-30` is the first date after `2010-07-27` which is more than 2 days apart.

Comment: Why does first row start from '2010-07-27' instead of '2010-07-26'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])

# compute time interval between every row with the last row
time_interval = pandas.Series.to_frame(df['date'] - df['date'].shift(1))
# Give the first time interval a meaningful value
time_interval['date'][0] = pandas.Timedelta('0 days')
# Define the gap
gap = pandas.Timedelta('2 days')

# get the index which satisfies the criteria
result = list(df[time_interval['date'] > gap].index)
new_result = result[:]

# insert its previous index
for i in range(len(result)):
    index = result[i]
    prev_index = index - 1
    if (prev_index >= 0) and (prev_index not in result):
        new_result.insert(new_result.index(index), prev_index)

# get desired rows by the index list
result = df.loc[new_result]
print(result)
```

## output

```
        date  value
1 2010-07-27   5.00
2 2010-07-30   3.00
5 2010-08-02   0.05
6 2010-08-05   0.05
```

## Update:

inspired by Scott Boston

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])

index = (df['date'] - df['date'].shift(1)).dt.days > 2

for i in range(len(index)):
    if (i > 0) and index[i]:
        index[i - 1] = True

print(df.loc[index])
```

## Update again

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'])

index = (df['date'] - df['date'].shift(1)).dt.days > 2
index_prev = (df['date'] - df['date'].shift(-1)).dt.days < -2

index = (index | index_prev)

print(df.loc[index])
```

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration too. @ScottBoston

Comment: @ShiXiuFeng How can we do the same with minute